# Kotlin (Mutable)List<(raw) kotlin.Any?> cast to List<JsonObject>

Tags: java, list, kotlin, mutable

in my code i get an io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray and i want to have a List of JsonObjects. 
So in Java i called jsonarray.getList() and get List - getList() returns a java.util.List.

So in Kotlin

```
var list: List<JsonObject> = jsonArray.getList()
```

but i get an error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.(Mutable)List<(raw) kotlin.Any?>! but kotlin.collections.List<io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject> was expected
```

Can i cast or so?

Thx

Answer (score 4):

`JsonArray` can hold both primitive and complex objects:

```
val jsonArray = JsonArray("""[1, {"foo": "bar"}, "stack"]""")
println(jsonArray.toList()) // -> [1, {foo=bar}, stack]
println(jsonArray.toList().map { it?.javaClass?.simpleName }) // -> [Integer, JsonObject, String]
```

`JsonObject` in turn represents a non primitive object. In other words it's not suitable to represent `"stack"`, `5.4`, `false`. If you're sure that the `jsonArray` holds only `JsonObject` instances you can do:

```
val jsonArray = JsonArray("""[{"foo": "bar"}]""")
println(jsonArray.toList()
        .map { it as JsonObject }
        .map { it.getString("foo")})
```